# how to get the coordinates of a contour

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, object-detection, contour

I am using OpenCV4Android version 2.4.11 and I am detecting any rectangular shapes in frames retrieved by camera. As shown in image_1 below, i draw a contour of a black color around the detected object, and what I am trying to do 
is, to get all the coordinates of the drawn contour the one that is ONLY drawn in black. What I attempted is, as shown in *code_1* below, i get the largest contour and the index of the largest contour and save them in the 
"largestContour" and "largest_contour_index" respectively. Then, I draw the contour using

```
Imgproc.drawContours(mMatInputFrame, contours, largest_contour_index, new Scalar(0, 0, 0), 2, 8, hierachy, 0, new Point());
```

and then I pass points of the largest contour to the class FindCorners because i want to find the specific coordinates of the contour drawn in black as follows:

```
this.mFindCorners = new FindCorners(largestContour.toArray());
double[] cords = this.mFindCorners.getCords();
```

the following line of code:

```
double[] cords = this.mFindCorners.getCords();
```

should gives me the smalle x-coordinates, smallest y-coordinates, largest x-coordinates and largest y-coordinates. But when i draw a circle around the coordinates i got from "this.mFindCorners.getCords();" i got something like
in image_2 below, which is just the corners of the BoundingRect.

Actually i do not want any coordinates from the boundingRect i want to have access to the coordinates of the contour that is drawn around the detected object in balck

please let me know how to get the coordinates of the contour itself?

**code_1**:

```
if (contours.size() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
        contour2f = new MatOfPoint2f(contours.get(i).toArray());
        approxDistance = Imgproc.arcLength(contour2f, true) * .01;//.02
        approxCurve = new MatOfPoint2f();
        Imgproc.approxPolyDP(contour2f, approxCurve, approxDistance, true);
        points = new MatOfPoint(approxCurve.toArray());

        double area = Math.abs(Imgproc.contourArea(points, true));
        if (points.total() >= 4 && area >= 40000 && area <= 200000) {
            if (area > largest_area) {
                largest_area = area;
                largest_contour_index = i;
                pointsOfLargestContour = points;
                largestContour = contours.get(i);
            }
        }
    }

    if (largest_area > 0) {
        Imgproc.drawContours(mMatInputFrame, contours, largest_contour_index, new Scalar(0, 0, 0), 2, 8, hierachy, 0, new Point());

        this.mFindCorners = new FindCorners(largestContour.toArray());
        double[] cords = this.mFindCorners.getCords();

        Core.circle(mMatInputFrame, new Point(cords[0], cords[1]), 10, new Scalar(255, 0, 0));
        Core.circle(mMatInputFrame, new Point(cords[2], cords[3]), 10, new Scalar(255, 255, 0));
    }
```

**FindCorners**:

```
public class FindCorners {
private final static String TAG = FragOpenCVCam.class.getSimpleName();

private ArrayList<Double> mlistXCords = null;
private ArrayList<Double> mlistYCords = null;
private double mSmallestX;
private double mSmallestY;
private double mLargestX;
private double mLargestY;
private double[] mCords = null;

public FindCorners(Point[] points) {
    this.mlistXCords = new ArrayList<>();
    this.mlistYCords = new ArrayList<>();
    this.mCords = new double[4];

    Log.d(TAG, "points.length: " + points.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        this.mlistXCords.add(points[i].x);
        this.mlistYCords.add(points[i].y);
    }

    //ascending
    Collections.sort(this.mlistXCords);
    Collections.sort(this.mlistYCords);

    this.mSmallestX = this.mlistXCords.get(0);
    this.mSmallestY = this.mlistYCords.get(0);
    this.mLargestX = this.mlistXCords.get(this.mlistXCords.size() - 1);
    this.mLargestY = this.mlistYCords.get(this.mlistYCords.size() - 1);

    this.mCords[0] = this.mSmallestX;
    this.mCords[1] = this.mSmallestY;
    this.mCords[2] = this.mLargestX;
    this.mCords[3] = this.mLargestY;
}

public double[] getCords() {
    return this.mCords;
}
```

}

**image_1**:

[image]

**image_2**:

[image]

**update**
i do not want to have the coordinates of the bounding rect, what i want to have is, the exact coordinates of the black contour. as shown in image_3 the coordinates i am getting from my code are where the red and yellow circles are..but i am looking for having access to the coordinates of the black line "contour" so i can draw some circles on it as shown in image_3. the spots in green are just to show you where i want to have coordinates.

**image_3**:

[image]

Comment: _should gives me the smalle x-coordinates, smallest y-coordinates, largest x-coordinates and largest y-coordinates._ These **are** the coordinates of the bounding box.  You probably want the 4 corners after `approxPolyDP` instead

Comment: @Miki as you see in my code, i have the following line "Imgproc.approxPolyDP(contour2f, approxCurve, approxDistance, true);" is the black contour containd in "approxCurve" ??

Comment: the black contour is `largestContour`

Comment: @Miki but when passed "largestContour" to this.mFindCorners = new FindCorners(largestContour.toArray());
                double[] cords = this.mFindCorners.getCords(); and when i draw a circle around the coordinates stored in "cords", i get corners like the ones shown in image_2 which the bounding rect not the black contour

Comment: Now in `FindCorners` you are computing the bounding rect of the black countour, and then you plot the circles on the top-left and bottom-right corner. If this is not what you want to do, what do you want to do exactly? Can you post an image where you manually draw the points you want to obtain?

Comment: @Miki nice idea...please have a loog at the update section

Comment: Those green points are points contained in `largestContour`. In order to get better results, I recommend to take the `convexHull` of `largestContour`. If you then need the 4 _corners_ of thea shape, use applyPolyDP (with appropriate parameters) and get the 4 resulting points.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have sorted x's and y's separately and it is obvious that your algorithm will find the red and yellow points.
    I can suggest the following algorithm:

```
int min_x=INF, min_x_index, min_y=1000, min_y_index;
int max_x=-1, max_x_index, max_y=-1, max_y_index;
 for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) 
    {
        if(points[i].x < min_x) { min_x = points[i].x; min_x_index = i; }
        if(points[i].x > max_x) { max_x = points[i].x; max_x_index = i; }
        if(points[i].y < min_y) { min_y = points[i].y; min_y_index = i; }
        if(points[i].y > max_y) { max_y = points[i].y; max_y_index = i; }
    }
Point corner1(points[min_x_index]);
Point corner2(points[min_y_index]);
Point corner3(points[max_x_index]);
Point corner4(points[max_y_index]);
```